# Retrieve a dictionary and add properties in an object with Open XML and CSharp

Tags: c#, dictionary, openxml

I have this project for my school where you need to read a file.xlsx with Open XML and C#.

e.g. You have a the file named "Zoo.xlsx" :

| Name | Species | Family | Sex | Date Of Birth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Zoe | Elephant | Elephantidae | F | 03/19/2004 |
| Victor | Deer | Cervidae | M |  |
| Camille | Eagle | Accipitridae | F | 09/03/2108 |
| END |  |  |  |  |

Then I have "XlsxFileTest.cs"

```cs
namespace MySchool.UnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class XlsxFileTest
    {
        private XlsxFile file;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Setup()
        {
            file = new file();
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void Cleanup()
        {
        }
        
        [TestMethod]
        [DeployementItem("Ressources\\Zoo.xlsx")]
        public void LoadSuccessedTest()
        {
            var fileLoad = file.Load("Zoo.xlsx");
            Assert.IsNotNull(file.Zoo);
        }
    }
}
```

I have my Animal class in "XlsxAnimal.cs"

```
namespace MySchool.Library
{
    public class Animal
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Species { get; set; }
        
        public string Family { get; set; }

        public string Sex { get; set; }

        public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And finally I have "XlsxFile.cs"

```cs
namespace MySchool.Library
{
    public class Xlsxfile
    {
        public dictionary<string, Animal> Zoo { get; private set; }

        public bool Load(string fileName)
        {
            bool returnValue = false;
            if (LoadAnimal(fileName))
            {
                returnValue = true;
            }
            return returnValue;
        }

        private bool LoadAnimal(fileName)
        {
            bool returnValue = false;
            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
            {
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = ExcelHelper.GetWorksheetFromSheetname(workbookPart, "ZOO")
                sheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
                Zoo = new Dictionary<string, Animal>();
                foreach (Row row in worksheetPart.Worksheet.elements<Row>().FirstOrDefault())
                {
                   Animal animal = new Animal
                   {
                        Name = ExcelHelper.GetCellValue(workbookPart, sheetData, "A" + row.RowIndex.ToString())
                        Species = ExcelHelper.GetCellValue(workbookPart, sheetData, "B" + row.RowIndex.ToString())
                        Family = ExcelHelper.GetCellValue(workbookPart, sheetData, "C" + row.RowIndex.ToString())
                        Sex = ExcelHelper.GetCellValue(workbookPart, sheetData, "D" + row.RowIndex.ToString())
                        DateOfBirth = ExcelHelper.GetCellValue(workbookPart, sheetData, "E" + row.RowIndex.ToString())
                    }
                    Zoo.Add(animal.Name, animal);
                    returnValue = true;
                }
            }   
            return returnValue;
        }   
    }   
}
```

I need to put each Name in the dictionary "Zoo" for Key and the class Animal for Value, and I need to put every information in the Class Animal.
And I don't want "END" in my dictionary or as an "Animal".
I have an error that say "AssertFailedException" for my `Assert.IsNotNull(file.Zoo);`.

Comment: Are you it's no Name as key and Animal as value? That way you can look up animals by name. And that's what your code seems to attempt.

Comment: What is your question here? What doesn't work? The code seems sort of OK, provided the ExcelHelper does what it's supposed to.

Comment: @PalleDue I have `public Dictionary<string, Animal> Zoo {get; private set;}`. When I try to Load with an `Assert.IsNotNull(file.Zoo)`. I have an error "AssertFailedException"

Comment: You aren't showing the problematic code then. Where is file initilized? And is the Zoo you are asserting the same you are adding to? Why don't you create a local variable `var zoo = new Dictionary<string, Animal>();` and return that instead of the boolean? It would be easier testable.

Comment: @PalleDue You are wright about value and key, I need to edit my question.

Comment: I have a `public bool Load (string fileName) {bool returnValue = false; if(LoadAnimal(fileName)) returnValue = true;}` in the same code but in an another one called "XlsxFileTest.cs" where file is initialized, I have : `public void LoadSuccessedFile() {var fileLoad = file.Load("Zoo.xlsx"); Assert.IsNotNull(file.Zoo); }`

Comment: Since LoadAnimal initializes something called Zoo, it cannot be the same Zoo we are talking about. And please add code to the question, others might not want to read 10 comments to find all details. A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is needed.

Comment: @PalleDue is that better ? I'm sorry, first time on Stack Overflow

Comment: I guess it's better, since there is now more info, but shouldn't LoadAnimal be part of the Xslxfile class? The Zoo you are adding to is not the one in Xslxfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment trail is getting a little long, so here is my version of what would work:

```cs
public class XlsxFile
{
    // Zoo is initialized here, no need to defer it to load
    public dictionary<string, Animal> Zoo { get; private set; } = new dictionary<string, Animal>();

    // Load just wraps private method LoadAnimals, no need to have it
    // public bool Load(string fileName)

    // I've changed the name to show that it loads multiple Animals and made it public. It's also part of the XlsxFile class now.
    public bool LoadAnimals(fileName)
    {
        bool returnValue = false;
        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = ExcelHelper.GetWorksheetFromSheetname(workbookPart, "ZOO")
            sheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
            // I couldn't figure what FirstOrDefault was doing here, didn't you want all rows?
            foreach (Row row in worksheetPart.Worksheet.elements<Row>())
            {
                Animal animal = new Animal
                {
                    // I skipped all the ToString's and used interpolated strings 
                    Name = ExcelHelper.GetCellValue(workbookPart, sheetData, $"A{row.RowIndex}")
                    Species = ExcelHelper.GetCellValue(workbookPart, sheetData, $"B{row.RowIndex}")
                    Family = ExcelHelper.GetCellValue(workbookPart, sheetData, $"C{row.RowIndex}")
                    Sex = ExcelHelper.GetCellValue(workbookPart, sheetData, $"D{row.RowIndex}")
                    DateOfBirth = ExcelHelper.GetCellValue(workbookPart, sheetData, $"E{row.RowIndex}")
                }
                Zoo.Add(animal.Name, animal);
                returnValue = true; // No need to set this every time you load an animal
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

See the comments for what I've changed. Now this should work:

```cs
var file = new XlsxFile();
bool fileLoad = file.LoadAnimals("Zoo.xlsx"); 
Assert.IsNotNull(file.Zoo);
Assert.IsTrue(file.Zoo.ContainsKey("Zoe"));
Assert.AreEqual("F", file.Zoo["Zoe"].Sex);
```